# How can I see where I'm using my EOS RAM?

Tags: ram

I have around 5KB of EOS RAM used. I know that about 3KB are used in the account creation , but....

How can I see which contracts and tables the rest of the EOS RAM used for?

Comment: you can only check all the actions you send, and find out what may cost your ram

Answer (score 7):

There is currently no method to know which tables your RAM is sitting in. The only way you could figure this out is to look at everything you ever did, check the code for the smart contracts where you did it, and try to figure out from that where your RAM is.

Comment: Any idea why the RAM deltas of all my transactions don't add up to my used RAM? See [How do I calculate my used and total RAM balances?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/5881/how-do-i-calculate-my-used-and-total-ram-balances)

Answer (score 2):

Now, we can see where the RAM has been used with bloks.io explorer. They have added a RAM explorer tool.

An example:

https://bloks.io/account/eosnewyorkio#ram-explorer

Comment: Upvoted for being the closest solution to the actual question. It may have limitations, but currently its the simplest solution for average users.

Comment: I don't see the "RAM Explorer" tab. I guess they removed it?