# How do I calculate my used and total RAM balances?

Tags: transactions, ram

I need help calculating how much RAM I've used and how much RAM I have (total)

I've read these questions and their answers:

- [How can I see where I'm using my EOS RAM?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/1934/how-can-i-see-where-im-using-my-eos-ram)
- [Where is my RAM currently allocated to?](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2226/where-is-my-ram-currently-allocated-to)

[confused00's answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/2231/3491) says to "check all actions sent in the past and look up if any of the contracts that they interacted with use their RAM". But how exactly do I do that? Is it possible to do that just by looking at [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/), or some other EOS block explorer? Or do I need to install the [EOSIO software suite](https://developers.eos.io/manuals/eos/latest/install/index) on my computer and use [cleos](https://eos.io/for-developers/build/cleos/)?

I tried doing it just by looking at [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/). I just looked at the initial transaction and every transaction with a little blue [microchip icon](https://fontawesome.com/icons/microchip) next to it. But the results of my calculations don't match the totals [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/) shows. (Correct me if I'm wrong, but I guess that [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/) uses "KB" to mean 1,024 bytes, not 1,000 bytes, and that [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/) rounds KB to the nearest hundredth with something like [Google Sheets' ROUND function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440).)

For example, let's look at two arbitrary accounts (below). Upon creation, each account gained 8,192 bytes of RAM (total) and used 3,446 of those bytes.

1. [heztcnbygege](https://www.bloks.io/account/heztcnbygege): an account without sent actions

   For this account, [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/) says "RAM used - 3.37 KB / 7.96 KB".

   `ROUND(3,446 / 1,024, 2)` = 3.37, which matches the KB of RAM used.

   But `ROUND(8,192 / 1,024, 2)` = 8.00, which is 0.04 KB more than the KB of RAM total.
2. [heztcnbxgyge](https://www.bloks.io/account/heztcnbxgyge): an account with sent actions

   For this account, [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/) says "RAM used - 3.49 KB / 9.33 KB".

   This account has a few transactions that are each marked with a blue microchip:

   1. [264c745c](https://www.bloks.io/transaction/264c745c3489c7df783276eaa333b49b01856fd75388e4eeeec97f3817a4f3d4): Consumed 600 bytes
   2. [0260e601](https://www.bloks.io/transaction/0260e601a03047262ec053dcb66e6684a4dc5f43683071d85d118306a13755f2): Released 268 bytes
   3. [e775e091](https://www.bloks.io/transaction/e775e09152ddcab7b73c0fce5b2aba60d84b739877355efa03f19dc76a55541a): Consumed 128 bytes

   But `ROUND((3,446 + 600 - 268 + 128) / 1,024, 2)` = 3.81, which is 0.32 KB more than the KB of RAM used.

   And `ROUND(8,192 / 1,024, 2)` = 8.00, which is 1.33 KB fewer than the KB of RAM total.

What am I getting wrong in calculating the RAM balances above? Also, how can I see the used and total RAM balances in exact bytes, instead of rounded to hundredths of KB?

Ultimately, in order to calculate my capital gains taxes, I need to record how much RAM I've gained or lost for each of my transactions, but since my calculations don't add up to [bloks.io](https://www.bloks.io/)'s totals, I guess I don't have the right numbers.

Comment: if you still need help with this question please post it in the eosio devs telegram channel: https://t.me/joinchat/0uhWYfXVpPlkNTA1

Comment: @ovi I still need help, but I don't use Telegram.